# Custom HTML Element: on-accept attribute

Tags: html, angular, custom-element

Im having a little trouble with a Custom HTML Element when using it inside Angular.

When adding the custom html element like this:

```
<custom-element *ngIf="something == false" 
    application-name="CUSTOM_NAME" 
    another-attribute="SOME_LINK">
</custom-element>
```

I can see the element in the DOM just fine, and it has 2 attributes:

`application-name` and `another-attribute`

However, if I add another attribute called `on-accept`, I assume, that the third attribute is turned into an event, as I cannot see all 3 attributes in the DOM.

```
<custom-element *ngIf="something == false" 
    application-name="CUSTOM_NAME" 
    another-attribute="SOME_LINK" 
    on-accept="SOME_EVENT">
</custom-element>
```

when doing an ng-serve, it gives me this Error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/main/main.component.html:5:118 - error TS2339: Property 'SOME_EVENT'
does not exist on type 'MainComponent'.

5 <custom-element *ngIf="something == false" application-name="CUSTOM_NAME" policy-link="SOME_LINK" 
on-accept="SOME_EVENT" ></custom-element>
```

When I rename `on-accept` to `onAccept` it works just fine.

Note: I want to decouple my custom HTML element from Angular completely as I would also like to use it in other apps aswell. And I want to use an attribute called `on-accept`, but apparently i cannot use custom attribute `on-accept` on my custom element, when inside an Angular app...
This makes it non-reusable.

If I use my custom element in some plain HTML file, I get expected bahaviour, and it shows me an element with 3 custom attributes:

`application-name`, `another-attribute` and `on-accept`

Why can I not use an attribute called `on-accept` within my Angular App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular templates:  on-xy="..." is like (xy)="..." ,  so on-accept="yourMethod()" is like (accept)="yourMethod()"

Your "SOME_EVENT" should be an existing function in your component. Try this:

MainComponent:

```
onAcceptEvent(evt) { console.info(evt); }
```

Template:

```
<custom-element *ngIf="something == false" on-accept="onAcceptEvent($event)" ></custom-element>
```

Comment: thanks, yes i know, thats what the Error msg states. But that also means, when using custom html elements attributes starting with on-* cannot be seen as real attributes when used in angular. I assume there is no way around this. Just weird having the same custom element behave differently on different setups. I think thats generally something I would not want to have, as I want my custom element to be reusable across different projects no matter if its an angular project or something else

Comment: 'weird' behavior imposed by the **host**. if I write an application that (just for example) removes all ``id`` attributes from an element, it is my fault when things go wrong, not your Custom Element. That means Custom Element developers need to be careful with attributes. If you want your CE to run everywhere (by default impossible as you can't control every environment) you have to be very-very-very careful with attributes. This Angular behavior is indeed annoying, but now we know